# Slow performance of apache web server on azure windows virtual machine

Tags: azure

I have installed uniform server and wamp and they both have a very slow response time.

I tried both the windows 2012 and 2008 server and I see the same problem: slow response time.

To reproduce this issue, install wamp or uniform server and try to open phpmyadmin in your web browser. You will notice that clicking on phpmyadmin menu items, there will be a 1.5 or 2 seconds lag until you get a response from server. Why is this happening?

**EDIT : >>>**

- Server memory usage looks ok: 45%.
- CPU usage is normal: When I click on a link(php) the CPU goes from idle to 15% for about 2 seconds.
- I tried two virtual machine sizes: extra small and small on both windows 2012 server and windows 2008 server. They have exactly the same behavior on this issue.
- Every hit has exactly the same lag.
- Yes, MySql is installed with uniform server. Also mysql is installed with wamp. I tried both
- I installed a preconfigured ubuntu linux VM with mantis bug tracking software on extra small VM and it runs very fast. So I think that this problem has to do with the OS or some configuration setting in apache, mysql or php.

Comment: Do some profiling on the server. Is the lag network-based, memory-based, CPU-based, disk-based, or something else (config/etc)?

Comment: Also, what server size are you using?

Comment: Please edit your answer to specify VM size, as this will be part of the equation. And... please clarify if it's just the first hit that has lag, or every hit.

Comment: One more clarification needed: When you install the uniform server, are you also installing MySQL on the same VM?

Comment: Edited the original question to add additional info on this issue

Comment: Had the same issue a while back, but I was unable to solve it. Ended up having to switch to AWS (LAMP stack). It seems like a generalized issue with Azure. I'd be interested to know if anyone solves this.

Comment: Next question(s). What disk did you install Apache and MySQL onto? You should **not** use the drives that are part of the default VM. You should instead create an additional VHD disk (I'd guess you should disable read and write caching but dunno) and install these on there. Also, be aware that you can actually stripe VHDs to increase disk I/O. Each Storage Account is limited to ~20k IOPS but if you take 4 25GB VHDs, each in different storage accounts, and stripe them, you could then get ~80k IOPS. Just be aware of other concerns if you stripe disks (doesn't play well with geo-replication).

Comment: @Jaxidian: Why all this complexity? Windows OS in on VHD, Apache in another VHD, MySQL in another VHD. The lamp stack runs fine on azure linux VM. It should run on azure windows VM.

Comment: I just installed zpanel application stack (apache,php,mysql,hmailserver) and the lag remains the same

Comment: Just found this post here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,91602,page=2 . Changing phpmyadmin config file to access mysql from localhost to 127.0.0.1 made phpmyadmin torespond very quick - <0.2sec . It looks that this lag has to do with localhost and mysql. investigating further...

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis Consider traditional servers. If you run everything off of one disk, you're going to have disk I/O bottlenecks. Already, your OS disk is heavily utilized. If you want high performance on other things, you should put them in their own disk. In Azure, you also must make sure the disk is in its own Storage Account since each storage account has its own I/O limitations. If you RAID0 4 VHDs in separate storage accounts, it's like RAID0'ing 4 different physical disks. Not really any different than traditional servers. But if you have another lead, don't let this be discouragement.

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis If you're running Windows, then you should assume both the C: and the Temp drive are second or third-tier storage devices and if you want a primary-tier storage device, you must add it. If second-tier is sufficient, then go with your C:. Your Temp drive will be wiped upon reboots, so definitely don't use that!

Comment: @Jaxidian I tried what you suggested. Added MySQL and Apache on different disks and the lag remains. It is an issue with localhost in connection string. If I change localhost with '127.0.0.1' in database config, it runs fine.

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis Did you ever follow my first suggestion: Profile it to find where the delay was? Is it in the networking stack? Based on changing networking settings, could be something DNS related or something there?

Comment: @Jaxidian Yes, it is not a Disk/CPU/Memory issue. It is probably a bug in php/mysql or windows server 2008/2012. There is a conversation on this matter on wampserver forum link I posted before

Comment: @YiannisMpourkelis If that's the case, the changing your disk strategy wouldn't change anything.

Answer (score -2):

You can try following the 3 points below:

- Disable the Windows Firewall.
- Disable IPv6 support.
- Edit the 'hosts' file.